# connecting between two subnets via VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn

I am trying to use `mount -t cifs` command from my computer to my raspberry pi when i am on the same network there are no issues ssh into the device mount from my computer to the rpi all good

The problem i am facing is when im remote I have been able to connect office's network using the ISP vpn which allows me to ssh to the device but i am unable to mount using cifs.

The vpn is open on all ports on my mac file sharing is on

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<IP>/path/to/share /place/to/mount -o username=<>,password=<>,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -     g),vers=3.0
[ 2397.231198] CIFS: Attempting to mount.

[ 2407.430247] CIFS: VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.

[ 2407.430294] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
```

was expected to mount my dir.

is this a problem in connecting our subnets?